# Should this become the reference "mileage" question?

Tags: discussion

We've had a few questions that distill down to "hey, how do I measure mileage?"

[Pulsar 180 - How Can I Measure the Mileage?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3511/57)

[Can I save money using E85 in my flexible fuel vehicle?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3394/57)

It's not like it's a hard process but we could facillitate some of the answers if we had a reference question and set of answers that we could point to.  For instance, if we had another equivalent of "Is E85 cost-effective?" we could say "first, check your mileage like this question over here", possibly even closing the question as a duplicate.

The "Pulsar" question is currently the most refined question about mileage in the database.  Should we make that the reference that we point to?  It would need some editing to make it applicable to all vehicles rather than a specific brand of bike.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we should turn the Pulsar mileage question into a wiki, but might create one and use that as the canonical reference when anyone needs a link to info about mileage.

Comment: Would that be something applicable for community wiki?